How do I report a Pop! OS documentation bug?
I used to be able to just file bug reports on Launchpad, but now, with the ubuntu-bug application I am defeated. Specifying the package results in an error telling me that it cannot collect any information, presumably because the files are not text files not binaries or, perhaps because I'm running Pop! OS,-- even though apt-cache tells me that the package I'm trying to file a report on is maintained by Ubuntu Developers...
(Despite the fact that Ubuntu Developers maintain the package, apparently Ask Ubuntu is not the place to ask about Ubuntu Developer maintained packages if they're on other distributions.)

I just discovered I was still able to file a bug directly on Launchpad by explicitly using /pop-os/ in the URL (https://bugs.launchpad.net/pop-os/).
